# multiple functions onClick not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to get a sound to play when I click a button and have it take me to a new page. Seems to work just fine in other browsers like Firefox but it's not working in Chrome. Here is the code I'm using.

```
<audio id="audio" src="soundfile.ogg"></audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('audio').play(); document.location = 'newpage.html'">Click</button>
```

I know .ogg files work so that's not the problem as this code below will work fine in Chrome.

```
<button onclick="SomeFunction(); document.getElementById('audio').play()">Click</button>
```

It only seems to give me a problem when I try to go to a new page. If anyone knows how I can get this to work in Chrome that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ot make sure the audio starts before leaving the page (maybe let it finish first as well). Put a delay on the location.href.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using:

```
window.open('newpage.html','_blank');
```

instead of:

```
document.location = 'newpage.html'
```

When you click the button you are opening another page in the same tab, if you open another tab, the music will still be playing in the other.

If doesn't help, hit me back!